# Bible Memorization App

Tags: bible

I am writing a Bible Memorization App. It will have no ads and have no cost. What versions of the Bible can I use? Obviously the entire Bible will be contained in the app but less than 200 verses will be used and only one at a time will appear on screen. Credits can be given for all versions used.

Right now I have KJV in xml form as part of the app. I want to make the app so it does not require the internet or data connection. So I will include internally the xml for each version I can use.

Can I safely use NIV, ESV, and HCSB or others without legal troubles? No money or solicitation will be made for the app (no ads and no cost).

Thanks for any guidance or suggestions.

Comment: As far as I understand it, different copyrighted versions of the bible have different fair use policies; so a comprehensive answer to your question would be a bit too broad for this site's format. Additionally, the minituae of copyright law is not on topic here, so the best we can probably do is either direct you to the linked question above, or suggest you research the fair use policy of each particular version you are interested in.

Comment: Copyright laws vary from country to country, so any usage would need to take into account the laws of every country where you will allow the app to be accessed.  Revenue is irrelevant for copyright.